# image showing null after navigating in flutter

Tags: flutter, image, dart, camera, face-detection

Below is the code where I am capturing image and navigating to next screen. I checked if picture is captured or not by print in console, it shows a path with .jpg extension. I want this image to be sent to next screen.
But it showing null is not a type of subtype image.

````
   if (picture != null) {
     print("Image captured successfully");
     final path = picture.path;
     if (path != null && File(path).existsSync()) {
       print(path);
       final inputImage = InputImage.fromFilePath(path);
       if (inputImage != null) {
         print("input image path: , ${inputImage.filePath}");
           Navigator.push(
           context,
           MaterialPageRoute(
             builder: (context) => HomePage(
               isCreateUser: true,
               inputImage: inputImage,
             ),
           ),
         );
       } else {
         print("Failed to create InputImage from file path");
       }
     } else {
       print("Invalid image file path");
     }
   } else {
     print("Image capture failed or returned null");
   }
 }```
````

Comment: Kindly, provide `home_screen` code as well.